# Editing a definition of a function in the command line after writing it

Tags: python

How can I go back and edit this function definition in command line after writing it?

```
    >>> def a(s):
    ...   a = something()
    ...
    ...   print('something')
    ...
    >>> blablabla
    >>> somecode...
```

so now I want to go back and edit the definition, but I can't because this is command prompt and once you write a line you can't go back and edit it, some times I write lots of lines of code and I want to edit some lines, is there a solution for this?

Comment: Write `def ...` again to redefine the function. Yes this is cumbersome for long functions. The interactive CLI isn't the ideal environment to be editing long functions.

Comment: There are some alternative Python CLIs that make this a bit easier (e.g. [ipython](http://ipython.org/), [ptpython](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython)), but really if you find yourself doing this often you should just save your script to a file and edit it there.

Comment: You can't *edit* a function when using a console. Once you press Enter the function is defined. You can re-define it and to help you you can sometimes use the up-arrow to browse previous commands and edit the last definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just write again the same def a(s) function with the new changes you will override the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse through your statement history by using <kbd>↑</kbd>. When you have the correct line(s), you can edit it and run it again. It will overwrite the previous function definition as [IMB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62285318/6329629) said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done without rewriting the whole function.  I would recommend jupyter notebook or jupyter labs for little experiments like this.  it's free, and easy to learn.  easiest way to install it, is as part of the anaconda package (google it)